# Wpf ContextMenu Items Header Dynamic Binding not updating

Tags: wpf, binding, contextmenu, resourcedictionary

Developing a multi language app. Everything works fine except for the Headers in ContextMenu.

My resources files looks like:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <system:String x:Key="TbIconConnect">Connect</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="TbIconConnecting">Connecting</system:String>
...
```

Declared in App.xaml ResourceDictionary:

```
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <ResourceDictionary Source="Langs/English.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Langs/Spanish.xaml"/>

    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

The ContextMenu is declared in MainWindow.xaml :

```
<ContextMenu x:Shared="false" x:Key="SysTrayMenu">
    <MenuItem Foreground="Aqua" Header="{DynamicResource TbIconConnect}" Click="ContextMenuConnectClick" FontSize="14">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image Source="/Img/App/Connect.png" Width="15" Height="15"/>
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
...
```

Asociated to a TaskBarIcon this way:

```
<tb:TaskbarIcon x:Name="TBIcon"
    IconSource="{Binding ViewModel.Status, Converter={StaticResource TaskBarIconConverter}}"
    ContextMenu="{DynamicResource SysTrayMenu}"
    ToolTipText="{Binding ViewModel.TbIconToolTip, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</tb:TaskbarIcon>
```

And Switch language code is:

```
public void SwitchLanguage(Language lang)
{
    ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary();

    switch (lang)
    {
        case Language.English:
            dict.Source = new Uri(@"..\Langs\English.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        break;
        case Language.Spanish:
            dict.Source = new Uri(@"..\Langs\Spanish.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        break;
    }

    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
}
```

Everything inside the app changes on the fly, including child forms. But the ContextMenu items headers remains with the original language.

Any idea?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. It works fine for me.

Comment: Weird issue.. I fix it changing headers in code behind inside SwitchLanguage method, no mvvm but i need it working... I will investigate further